# problem with green's formula?

Tags: analysis

i have this question : 
we have this problem (dirichlet) : for $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $u$ function at least in $H^{1/2}$

\begin{equation*}
  \left\{
    \begin{aligned}
      -\Delta u&=f&\text{in $\Omega$}\\
      u&=0&\text{in $\partial \Omega$}\\
    \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation*}
to prove the unicity of the solution the autor says that we consider two solutions $u,v$ we find "BY GREEN'S FORMULA" that :

$\int_\Omega|\nabla(u-v)(x)|^2dx=0$ , so we will find  $u-v=constant$
my question is , how did he use green's formula to find that result ?

(he says by multiplication of $\Delta (u-v)$ by $u-v$ and green's formula we find the that result  )........
thank you very much .

Comment: The gradient term need to be squared.  Please see my answer and let me know how I can improve it.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi=u-v$.  Then, using the product rule for the divergence operator, ww can write

$$\phi \nabla^2 \phi=\nabla \cdot (\phi \nabla \phi)-\left|\nabla \phi\right|^2 \tag 1$$

Integrating $(1)$ and using the divergence theorem reveals

$$\int_{\Omega} \phi \nabla^2 \phi\
 dV=\oint_{\partial \Omega} \phi (\hat n \cdot \nabla \phi)\,dS-\int_{\Omega} \left|\nabla \phi\right|^2\,dV \tag 2$$

Now, using $\nabla^2 \phi=\nabla ^2(u-v)=0$ along with $\phi =u-v =0$ on $\partial \Omega$ in $(2)$, we arrive at

$$\int_{\Omega} \left|\nabla (u-v)\right|^2\,dV=0$$

And we are done!

Comment: thanks for unswering i can not read good the unswer can you please use some "$$"

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure.  I've edited so hopefully it is readable now.

Comment: i am trying to understand your unswer , so do you mean here by $V=\Omega$ and $S=\partial \Omega$ and the integrale with the circle is the integrale on the boundary ??

Comment: ok now is better

Comment: @@Dr. MV well first i didn't understand , why didn't you use $\Delta$ and only $\nabla$..

Comment: i mean is there a step that you didn't write , and that i don't see it ...?

Comment: I prefer the symbol $\nabla^2$ to represent the Laplacian Operator.

Comment: well that s new for me ... you mean $\nabla.\nabla u = \nabla^2u=\Delta u$ am i right ?

Comment: and then i think you mean this $\phi\nabla^2\phi=\phi\nabla.\nabla\phi=\nabla.(\phi\nabla\phi)$ bacause $\phi$ is a scalar function ??that s true ?

Comment: oooh but like that i won't find your equality so i did a mistake here but i d on t know where :) the only rule that i know is $\nabla \cdot (fv) = \nabla f \cdot v + f\nabla \cdot v$ for f scalar and v : vector field

Comment: Yes.  That is the product rule for the divergence.  Now, let $f=\phi$ and $\vec v=\nabla \phi$.

Comment: fine , thanks , i almost understand every thing .... just here when we have $\int_{\Omega} \phi \nabla^2 \phi\
 dV=\oint_{\partial \Omega} \phi (\hat n \cdot \nabla \phi)\,dS-\int_{\Omega} \left|\nabla \phi\right|^2\,dV \tag 2$ 

i know that $\oint_{\partial \Omega} \phi (\hat n \cdot \nabla \phi)\,dS$ =0, because it s zero on the boundary , but it stays $\int_{\Omega} \phi \nabla^2 \phi\
 dV=-\int_{\Omega} \left|\nabla \phi\right|^2\,dV \tag 2$ so did you deduce that $\int_{\Omega} \phi \nabla^2 \phi\
 dV=0$ too ?? and why

Comment: i mean is $\int_{\Omega} \phi \nabla^2 \phi\  dV=0$? to deduce our result ($-\int_{\Omega} \left|\nabla \phi\right|^2\,dV =0$)

Comment: because for me if $\phi=0$ on the boundary i am not sure if the integral on $\Omega$ will be equal to zero !

Comment: Since $\phi=u-v$, and both $u$ and $v$ satisfy $\nabla ^2u=f$ in $\Omega$, then $\nabla \phi=0$ in $\Omega$.

Comment: @ Dr. MV thank you very much , well done and good job

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.